# Dynamic treegrid context menus

Tags: gwt, gxt

Is there a way using the treegrid in gwt-ext to have different context menus for different rows?

For example I would like my leaf rows to have different menu options then my non-leaf rows, or at least be able to disable menu options when they aren't revelent to the row that was right clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution for this problem:

When you create the leafs, you should set the property "type" to "leaf", and the others to "non-leaf".

*BaseTreeModel base = new BaseTreeModel();
base.set("type", "leaf");*

So, in the selectionChanged event of your tree, you put the verification, and create the menu only for your leafs.

```
  *treePanel.getSelectionModel().addListener(Events.SelectionChange, new      SelectionChangedListener<ModelData>() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> data) {
            BaseTreeModel selected = (BaseTreeModel) data.getSelectedItem();
            if ("leaf".equals(selected .get("type").toString())) {
            // create the Menu and set it to contextMenu of your tree
            } else {
                treePanel.setContextMenu(null);
            }*
```

André.